# How can i fix this :AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip

Tags: python

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')


client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

in .env file:
TOKEN=...

How can i fix this i make like youtube but it doesn't working when i run it have an error is :
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: There is no `strip` method in the code you show, so it's unlikely the problem occurs directly here.

Comment: Having `TOKEN` in a file doesn't help if you don't *source* the file and ensure it becomes an environment variable. Otherwise, `os.getenv('TOKEN')` will not find the TOKEN in the environment, and return `None`. And `None` may not be a value `client.run()` can handle, if the error comes from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run client you need to pass your token for authentication like below;

```
client.run('my token goes here')
```

Did you defined your token as envoirement variable as 'TOKEN' or did you get that part of script from elsewhere. If you copied from youtube, content creator uses this way to pass his token to avoid showing his credential.

For authentication you need to create token first from below;
https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/

Comment: You missed the line "in .env file: TOKEN=..." in the question.